# Append the last message once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello guys i am trying to build a chat with Jquery , php , ajax and mysql
the problem that i am facing since few days is that when i get the value of the last message its keep getting append to the div what i want is to append the last message only once , and append again if there is a new message here is my ajax call

```
var chat = "";
     $.ajax({
            url: "php/gt_user.php",
            type: "get",
            success: function (result) {
                var gtUser = $.parseJSON(result);
                $.each(gtUser, function (idx, obj) {
                    var usrApp = "<span><i class='fa fa-user-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                    usrApp += "<p class='usr-name'>" + obj.Tables_in_chat + "</p></span>";
                    $('.userarea').append(usrApp);
                }); // here i get all the username who sent a message and print them on a div
                $('.userarea span').on('click', function () {
                    $('.msgarea').html("");
                    var usrName = $(this).text();
                    $('#usrname').text(usrName);
                    setInterval(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "php/admin_msg.php",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                name: usrName
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                var lastmsg = result;

                                function appedn() {
                                    var usrMsg = "<div class='usr-msg'><i class='fa fa-user-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                                    usrMsg += "<span><p>" + lastmsg + "</p></span></div>";
                                    $('.msgarea').append(usrMsg);
                                }

                                if (chat !== result) {
                                    appedn();

                                } else {
                                    chat = result;
                                }

                            }

                        });
                    }, 2000);


                });
            }
        });
```

the respanse from `php/admin_msg.php` is working and i got the last message sucessfully the problem is that this script keep adding the same message to the message area , and what i want is to added the message only once if there is a new one

Comment: can you post the response from php/admin_msg.php? I would include at timestamp/message id in the response and only get the new message, send 0 on the first request, and the latest retrieved message id in the following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was finally able to fix the problem after 1 day of struggle so will post the answear here just in case it will help some one else facing the same issue

the part where i had to get all the username table from database i move it to my HTML and used a few line of php to echo the result like this(each user name has his own table)

```
  // show all the user name that sent a message
    $result = $con->query("show tables from chat"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<span><i class='fa fa-user-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i><p class='usr-name'>".$row['Tables_in_chat']."</p></span>"; 
    }
```

then on my jquery script i moved the function that check for the last message every 2sec outside the click event so my Jquery script look more cleaner now

```
  /* get the user name and added it to the header of the message box  */
     $('.userarea span').on('click', function () {
            $('.msgarea').html("");
            var usrName = $(this).text();
            $('#usrname').text(usrName);

        });
        var chatdata = "";
   /* check for new message and append the message area if there is a new one */
        setInterval(function () {
            var usrName = $('#usrname').text();
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/admin_msg.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    name: usrName
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    function appedn() {
                        var usrMsg = "<div class='usr-msg'><i class='fa fa-user-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                        usrMsg += "<span><p>" + result + "</p></span></div>";
                        $('.msgarea').append(usrMsg);
                    }

                    if (chatdata !== result) {
                        appedn();
                        chatdata = result;
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow identify last message that is already appended to your html the best would be some id sent from server. So your message div should containt some `data-id` attribute, and then when you ask for next message get last children of `$('.msgarea')` element, read it `data-id` and compare with current one.

Another thing I would recommend to moving to some view library or framework, react, angular, vue or whatever. It gets complicated when you want to manage such features with pure jQuery.

Comment: yeah i am all most to the point where i think i should give up on that project just because of this behavior on the script , i taught i am missing something this is why i posted the question here